# Disable screen rotation of a xib in swift

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, swift-framework

I created a dynamic framework in swift wherein a .xib file inside my framework opens up whenever a voip notification lands.
I want to restrict the orientation of the screen to portrait mode only, but i am not sure how to do it.

I tried below methods but these can only be used in a UIViewController and not in UIView.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: You can't restrict a view's rotation, the one you can is the ViewController, so add something like this to the container viewcontroller you show your view in: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/disable-rotation-code-example-in-swift/

Comment: @BencePattogato I appreciate your suggestion but as i have mentioned i already did what you are suggesting. I am using VOIP notification along with callkit, therefore i dont know the active viewcontroller when a VOIP notification lands hence i want to restrict my UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long i finally figured out the solution.
I created a view controller class in my framework from which i am opening the .xib file.
I included the following function in my newly create view controller

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

now before opening the .xib i present this viewcontroller over the top of the current view controller i.e i called this viewcontroller from its own file, somewhat like this

self.navCtrl?.present(self, animated: false, completion: nil)

by doing so my .xib file is opened above my framework's viewcontroller rather than the app's view controller. to dismiss this viewcontroller, simply use

```
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Hence problem solved.